# How to whitelist IP’s on an Asus router to allow VOIP to pass through without dropped packets?

Tags: networking, router, voip

I recently installed my newly purchased an [Asus RT-N56U](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RTN56U/) and quickly noticed that I was getting disconnected from different VOIP services, namely both Mumble and TeamSpeak but otherwise my connection is healthy.

After inspecting the routers system log I noticed that it is riddled with “kernel: DROP” notices from the Mumble and TeamSpeak IP-addresses around the time of the disconnects.

I do not know if this is the reason behind all of this but I can find no way, probably due to my ignorance, to allow these IP’s to go through unhindered? Disabling "SIP" doesn't seem to have worked.

I managed to get a hold of ASUS support and they suggested I upgrade (or downgrade, I wasn't paying enough attention unfortunately) to a firmware version that they supplied me with. After that didn't fix the problem they claim the router is defective and are telling me to return it to the store where I purchased it.

I returned the old router and was given a new one of the same model yet the issues of connectivity persist. The DROP messages in the system log are however no longer present. Currently trying to map the disconnects with other messages in the system log to see if any of them are consistent.

Comment: See if your router has a option to "Disable SIP ALG". Many routers have a broken SIP algorithm which can cause problems with VoIP calls. See [What is SIP ALG and why does Gradwell recommend that I turn it off?](https://support.gradwell.com/hc/en-gb/articles/215553503-What-is-SIP-ALG-and-why-does-Gradwell-recommend-that-I-turn-it-off-)

Comment: @DavidPostill There seems to be one, it's called "SIP Passthrough" in the "NAT Passthrough" options. Before I disable it I would just like to ask what the possible ramifications are for doing so.

Comment: I've never heard of "SIP Passthrough".

Comment: After a short google search it seems that to disable SIP one has to disable "SIP passthrough". I just did that so will see if that fixes it. Doesn't seem to have removed the repeated "kernel: DROP" notices but so far it hasn't disconnected me from any of the VOIP services I'm running. Will be back later, maybe tomorrow, with an update. In the mean time, thank you for a quick response!

Comment: You are welcome. Let me know if it all works and then I will write a proper answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill Unfortunately it seems to not have worked, just got disconnected again and the system log is still filled with "kernel DROP:" messages from the respective IP's

Comment: Hmm. I've no idea what else you can try.

Comment: @DavidPostill I thank you for the time either way. Is there any way of "bumping" this question so that it is more visible? I figure that after 23 hours the question must be buried by now.

Comment: See [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: That was certainly not my intention. I'm just used to typical forum ways of browsing posts/questions. I am unfamiliar with how StackExchange works when it comes to presenting older questions.

Answer (score 0):

I see your router is capable of having dual WAN interfaces (having a second internet provider via the USB port). Are you using that feature? If so, that may be the reason for the disconnection. Be sure to have it configured as "Failover" and not "Load balance).

Other typical issue is that UDP NAT translations expire after some time without traffic. Does the disconnection happen after a period of time without voice exchange?

(Sorry, cannot post comments yet).

Comment: I am not (and haven't been) using the dual WAN interface. I also haven't noticed that it has followed a period of time without voice exchange however I will take note of it next time it happens.

Answer (score 0):

The disconnects sound like the registration port is not being left open long enough on the router for the applications to re-register. You could try to open port 5060 on your router for both TCP and UDP from any WAN IP to the LAN IP of your computer.